# Checking if input contains a name - python

Tags: python, python-3.x

It gives me the error 'int object is not iterable' when th isName() function runs. I dont really understand what is wrong. Any Ideas? Thanks!

```
import sys

def ifName():
    ifNameList = userInput.split()
    for i in len(ifNameList):
        #Seeing if one word following another word both have their first letters in capital
        if ifNameList[i] and ifNameList[i+1].istitle():
            print("is that a dude/dudette?")

userInput = input("type something")

if " " in userInput:
    ifName()
```

I changed

```
for i in len(ifNameList)):
```

to

```
for i in (range(len(ifNameList)))
```

now it gives me this error 'IndexError: list index out of range

UPDATE:
 I fixed everyhing by changing

```
for i in len(ifNameList):
            #Seeing if one word following another word both have their first letters in capital
            if ifNameList[i] and ifNameList[i+1].istitle():
                print("is that a dude/dudette?")
```

to

```
  for i in (range(len(ifNameList))):

        #Seeing if one word following another word both have their first letters in capital
        if i != 0:
            if ifNameList[i] and ifNameList[i-1].istitle():
                print("Is that a dude/dudette")
            else:
                print("That is not a dude/dudette")
        else:
           continue
```

Comment: What do you mean with `return`? You never instruct it to return anything? If you mean printing, you will have to give us more information such that the error is reproduceable.

Comment: Yes, it did. It was just me beeing a littly bit stupid

Comment: `for i in (range(len(ifNameList)))`

Comment: first you should change `if " " in userInput:` by `if userInput is not None:` or simply `if userInput:`

Comment: I want the user to type atleast two words.

Comment: Consider what `i+1` gives when `i` is the final item in the list.

Comment: Please explain what you want the program to do, so that we can easily understand what each bit of code is *trying* to accomplish. The code does **exactly** what you type, so if you only show us code without describing what you want the code to do, we can only assume you meant what you typed.

Comment: As the title suggests, I want to check if an input contains a name.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, [len](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#len) method returns an integer. So,

```
for i in len(ifNameList)):
```

is looping over an integer and hence the error 'int object is not iterable'

Secondly,

```
for i in (range(len(ifNameList)))
```

raises the error 'IndexError: list index out of range which is again valid because, you have a statement [i+1].

The first loop fetched index 0(i.e 'i') and 1(i.e 'i+1'). But the second loop fetched index 1(i.e 'i') and 2(i.e 'i+1').

The error will hence be raise while looping on the last index of the list, where it then tries to find last-index+1 index, which does not exist.

Looking at the problem defination, it seems you want to find the input words are whether satisfy the istitle() condition.

I would have written it something like following:

```
import sys

def ifName():
    ifNameList = userInput.split()
    non_title_names = []
    for each_name in ifNameList:
        #Seeing if one word following another word both have their first letters in capital
        if not each_name.istitle():
            non_title_names.append(each_name)
    if non_title_names:
        print("Not a dude/dudette?")
    else:
        print("is that a dude/dudette?")

userInput = input("type something:\t")

if " " in userInput:
    ifName()
```

Comment: Python 3 is tagged -  `raw_input()` is going to confuse.

Answer (score 0):

You are making a simple check overly complex.  This is one way to make your code at least work:

```
import sys

def ifName(userInput):
    ifNameList = userInput.split()
    if len(ifNameList) != 2:
        print("Please enter two names", file=sys.stderr)

    elif ifNameList[0].istitle() and ifNameList[1].istitle():
        #Seeing if one word following another word both have their first letters in capital
        print("is that a dude/dudette?")
    else:
        print("Please capilalize your names", file=sys.stderr)

    # Return something?

userInput = input("type something")

if " " in userInput:
    ifName(userInput)
```

But a few things to consider.  Your function should return something, right now it does very little.

Notice that I passed the user's input into the function as a parameter.  I see no good reason for using a global here.

You require the user to capitalise the names, why not do that in the program using `str.capitalize()`?

You are assuming that all names have two components.  Are you sure that is always the case?

It is unclear what you want to happen when there is an odd number of names, or at least not 2 names, entered.

Comment: Thanks. I can't think of a way to make it work with just a first name. The reason is I'm creating a chat robot and just checking for uppercase letters in a single word won't really work because the user won't be trying to write in a very formal way and therefor some words with capital letters might slip through. And my function works for more than 2 names. It just prints out "is that a dude/dudette" twice, which I can fix very easily.